# How to slice a np.array using a list of unknown length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

> I am probably using the wrong names/notation (and an answer probably exists on SO, but I can't find it). Please help me clarify so that I can update the post, and help people like me in the future.

I have an array `A` of unknown dimension `n`, and a list of indexes of unknown length `l`, where `l<=n`.

I want to be able to select the slice of `A` that correspond to the indexes in `l`. I.e I want:

```
A = np.zeros([3,4,5])
idx = [1,3]
B = # general command I am looking for

B_bad = A[idx] # shape = (2,4,5), not what I want!
B_manual = A[idx[0], idx[1]] # shape = (5), what I want, but as a general expression.
# it is okay that the indexes are in order i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a tuple:

```
>>> A[tuple(idx)]
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> A[tuple(idx)].shape
(5,)
```

Indexing with a `list` doesn't have the same meaning. See `numpy`'s [documentation on indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) for more information.